# Creating matrix from two lists and function

Tags: r

I have two lists and a function, like this:

```
ms <- c(1, 2, 3)
ns <- c(4, 5)
f <- function(m, n) {
    return result of some computation involving m and n
}
```

I want to get a table like this, where each entry is obtained by applying the function to each pair of elements in rows and cols:

```
         4       5
-------------------
1 | f(1, 4) f(1, 5)
2 | f(2, 4) f(2, 5)
3 | f(3, 4) f(3, 5)
```

How do I do this?  I don't want to use `for` loops.  I assume there is a way to do this using some form of `apply`.

Comment: Just fyi, when you change the names of all the variables in the question it makes the answers look like nonsense.  Best to tell the answerers in a comment under their answer when you change things, as they do not get notified of question edits

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I figured it wouldn't matter since I saw what you meant.  I guess that doesn't help the next guy much, though.  I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the result using `%*%`

```
rows%*%t(cols)
```

Or

```
 tcrossprod(rows, cols)
```

#### Update

Based on the edited OP's post,

```
outer(rows, cols, FUN=f)
```